# Backup installed packages and restore them later install those on another Ubuntu system without internet connection

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, python-packaging, install.packages, offline-mode, cuda-driver

Take backup of all installed packages files and restore those files in new server and install all the packages without internet.

I had tried with apt-clone method but it's taking backup and restoring the .ZIP file but it is asking for internet.I need to install without internet.

Comment: you should add commands you are using